# Is an assembly signed with a strong name before or after the post-build event?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, signing, post-build-event, strongname

I'm modifying the stack size of an assembly using `editbin`, see [Increase stack size of main program or create a new thread with larger stack size for recursive code blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56476465/7556646)

Now I'm asking myself: Is an assembly signed with a strong name before or after the post-build event? Because `editbin` is changing the assembly in the post-build event.

My post build-event looks like that:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /STACK:16777216 "$(TargetPath)"
```

And my project `.csproj` file contains the following lines:

```
<PropertyGroup>

  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>..\STRONGNAME.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>

</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>"$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\bin\editbin.exe" /STACK:16777216 "$(TargetPath)"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Wrong side up, you forgot to flip that coin again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assembly is signed with a strong name **before** the post-build event. That means `editbin` will change that assembly and the signature is not valid anymore.

`sn.exe -v assembly.exe` will return `Failed to verify assembly -- Strong name validation failed ...`

A workaround to get a valid signed assembly which was modified using `editbin` is to use the `AfterCompile` event and to resign the assembly using `sn`.

The Project file should look like that:

```
  <Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="
&quot;$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\bin\editbin.exe&quot; /STACK:16777216 &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)&quot;
echo $(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\
&quot;$(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\sn.exe&quot; -Ra &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\STRONGNAME.snk&quot;
" />
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>REM "See AfterCompile for stack size and resigning"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: If you enable MSBuild logging and take a look at the generated log entries, you should notice that the key file is used by the C# compiler. So of course, the strong name was generated before post build event.